# Using Browser Action Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a Chrome Extension which 'cleans' the links from Google Search results and then enables the user to see all the links from the search result and let them copy any URL from the list.

For example.

Manifest File.

```
{
   "content_scripts":[
      {
         "all_frames":true,
         "js":[
            "js/jquery.min.js",
            "js/clean.js"
         ],
         "matches":[
            "http://www.google.com.au/*",
            "https://www.google.com.au/*"
         ],
         "run_at":"document_start"
      }
   ],
   "description":"Cleans URLs and allows you to copy them to the clipboard.",
   "icons":{
      "16":"img/icon-16.png",
      "32":"img/icon-32.png",
      "64":"img/icon-64.png",
      "128":"img/icon-128.png",
      "256":"img/icon-256.png"
   },
   "browser_action":{
      "default_icon":{
         "16":"img/icon-16.png"
      },
      "default_title":"Clean Google",
      "default_popup":"html/index.html"
   },
   "manifest_version":2,
   "minimum_chrome_version":"40",
   "name":"Clean Google",
   "version":"1.0",
   "version_name":"1.0"
}
```

HTML file.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/clipboard.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/urls.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <table>
            <h3>Current Page</h3>
            <h4 class="tab"></h4>
            <tr>
                <td class="name">URL :</td>
                <td>
                    <p class="url">sample url</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" value="Copy URL" class="copy" data-clipboard-target=".url">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
</body>

</html>
```

urls JS File. (I'm not sure how to dynamically create the elements based on how many links there are)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    new Clipboard(".copy");
    var a = $("a").attr("href");
    var c = a.length;
    $("h4").text(window.location.href);
    $(".url").text(c);
});
```

Image of current Extension.

[image]

I hope this helps you understand what I want to achieve. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I guess you need to use a loop: `$("a").each(function() { do stuff with the current link in $(this) });`

Comment: Based from those clean URLs from the search result I would like to dynamically add them to that HTML file and allow the user to copy them. (This will be done in the browser action)

Comment: OK, so use a loop, and append a DIV for each one to the page.

Comment: Ok, thanks :) Also how do I access the DOM through the browser action?

Comment: Sorry, I don't actually know anything about writing extensions, just ordinary Javascript. I'm not sure how they access the DOM.

Comment: But I'm sure there are plenty of tutorials on writing browser extensions that explain it.

Comment: Ok, no worries. Thanks for those answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When user opened the popup window, you need inject a script on current page. Content-scripts or other injected scripts (via `chrome.tabs.executeScript`) have access to DOM and can listen and send messages inside your extension (background\content-script\popup\optiona-page).

Example popup script:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    // execute script on current tab only
    var tab = tabs[0];
    if(/https?:\/\//.test(tab.url)) // regexp for exec on need pages only
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: 'content.js'});            
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender) {
    if(message.action == 'get-links') {
        console.log(messages.links);
    }
});
```

and content.js:

```
var links = [];
var a = document.querySelectorAll('a');
for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
    links.push(a[i].getAttribute('href');
}

chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: 'get-links', links: links});
```

For this code you must write permissions in manifest: `"http://*/*"` (or whitelist) and `"tabs"`.

Comment: Downvoting, since messaging will not work like that.

Comment: @RyanHawdon Another function needs to be called from the popup - `chrome.tabs.sendMessage`. `chrome.extension` messaging functions are deprecated, receiving end should use `chrome.runtime.onMessage`. There's good documentation [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#simple). But I still don't get what your exact question is - you should improve it before it can be meaningfully answered. See [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Ok, thanks for that. To simplify the question I basically want to know how to use scripts in the browser action.

Comment: @Xan, He wants to get access to DOM of current page from Popup window. And you right about deprecated functions, i will update my post with your notices.

Comment: @Fenex While you're at it, consider that having a script that's injected on demand with `"activeTab"` permission is probably a better solution than messaging an always-injected one.

Comment: @Fenex Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @Xan Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Last remark: the only permission you need for this is `"activeTab"`, which produces no warning.

Comment: Ok, no worries. Thank you :)